# ASP.NET serving angular app and deployUrl is deprecated

Tags: asp.net, angular

I have an ASP.NET app (.NET 6.0), and I have a route `/ngxapp` which serves my angular 13 app. The angular app is copied to `wwwroot/ngxapp` folder (see below how it's built).

I've been using this .NET code for years to deliver *angular* app:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();

            // this is for reverse proxy (NGINX)
            app.UseForwardedHeaders(new()
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        // this must be before the next (angular) section, otherwise 404's are not handled
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute($"{ANGULAR_APP_ROUTE_S}/404");

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            RewriteXFrameOptionsHeader(context);

            await next();

            RedirectEmptyRootToAngularApp(context, ANGULAR_APP_ROUTE_S);

            await RewriteAssets(context, next);

            await RedirectForAngular(context, next, ANGULAR_APP_ROUTE_S);
        });

        app.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions {DefaultFileNames = new List<string> {"index.html"}});

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
```

It allows to open angular app even when user requests for some non-root angular route (for example, `https://<domain>.com/ngxapp/someroute-1/subroute/etc`). Basically, everything works like a charm.

Now, when I build an angular app I've always used `--deploy-url=/ngxapp/` param, like so (from windows batch .cmd file):

```
call ng build --base-href /%folder% --deploy-url /%folder%/ --configuration=production
```

The latest version of angular compiler shows me the warning about `deployUrl`:

> Option "deployUrl" is deprecated: Use "baseHref" option, "APP_BASE_HREF" DI token or a combination of both instead. For more information, see https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-deploy-url.

I read the docs on `APP_BASE_HREF` and built angular app ***without `--deploy-url`*** parameter. Also, used `APP_BASE_HREF`:

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [AppComponent, CreateUrlComponent, NotAuthorizedComponent, FormFocusDirective],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      AppRoutingModule,
      BrowserAnimationsModule,
      ...
   ],
   providers: [
      { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: environment.baseHref }, // baseHref = "/ngxapp"
      { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true }
   ],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
   constructor() {}
}
```

But now, when I run ASP.NET app with the angular app in place (opening `https://localhost/ngxapp` in the browser), the requests of all *.js* files are empty and their MIME type is `text/html`. Basically, they're not found.

If I return back to using `deploy-url` parameter in the angular build, everything works!

What am I missing here?

## Comes down to this

When `--deploy-url` is used, the request Url is correct:

> https://localhost:44389/ngxapp/filename.js
> because the *script* block contains correct url's:

```
<script src="/ngxapp/runtime.js" type="module"></script>
```

When `--deploy-url` is not used, ***ngxapp*** part is missing:

> https://localhost:44389/filename.js
> and the script block is:

```
<script src="runtime.js" type="module"></script>
```

Comment: Might be as simple as changing your %folder% var from /ngxapp/ to /nxgapp?

Comment: what do you mean? its value does not change

Comment: @alvipeo,  did you solve this problem? I'm running into exactly the same issue today.

Comment: No. I still use --deploy-url for now. BTW, I just checked the docs https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-deploy-url and it doesn't say it's deprecated.

Comment: I believe Abdus has the correct solution. You'll need to make sure the served page contains <base href="/ngxapp/" /> in the head. Then relative links will be relative to that base and the links should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work. Here's how I wanted the angular part to work within ASP.NET app:

if I have a special route for angular app called `/ngxapp` within my ASP.NET application, I want ***any*** link containing '/ngxapp' part to work seemlessly. For example, if a user paste `https://example.com/ngxapp/child/subchild` to a browser address, and the angular app does have `child/subchild` routes, then ASP.NET app should serve the `https://example.com/ngxapp/index.html` and the angular router takes over and serves `child/subchild`.

The problem is when ASP.NET serves angular's app `index.html` from `/ngxapp`, the script tags in the index file must have a valid path related to `wwwroot/ngxapp/` folder (`scr='/ngxapp/some-angular-file.js`, and not just `src='/some-angular-file.js'`). This works when `--deploy-url` flag is used.

Now, when the flag is deprecated, I had to create a rewrite rule in ASP.NET which actually catches any file served from angular app folder and rewrites it to the correct path accordingly: from `/whatever-angular-file.js` to `/ngxapp/whatever-angular-file.js`.

With this custom URL rewriting rule in place, everything works as expected, and `--deploy-url` is not needed.